# Share variables between classes and methods

Tags: c#, class, variables, methods

I wrote this and I get the following errors. Is there any simple way to make the variables see each others?

> Warning 1 The variable 'notepad_running' is assigned but its value is never used.
>
> Error 2 The name 'notepad_running' does not exist in the current context.
>
> Error 3 The name 'notepad_list' does not exist in the current context.

```
public class notepad_check_class
{
    public static void notepad_check()
    {
        Process [] notepad_list = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        if (notepad_list.Length > 0)
        {
            int notepad_running = 1;
        }
    }
}

public class kill_notepad_class
{
    public static void kill_notepad()
    {
        notepad_check_class.notepad_check();
        if (notepad_running = 1)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to kill all notepad processes?", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            foreach (Process notepad_process in notepad_list)
            {
                notepad_process.Kill();
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot find any running process of notepad.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you know you can get your code reviewed at [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)? There are a couple of design issues with your code on which you might gather feedback there.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it by putting public static properties in `notepad_check_class`:

```
public static Process[] NotepadList { set; get; }
public static int NotepadRunning { set; get; }
```

However I would suggest just one class:

```
public static class NotepadManager {

  private static Process[] NotepadList { set; get; }
  private static int NotepadRunning { set; get; }

  public static void Check() { ... }
  public static void Kill() { ... }

}
```

Comment: +1 for the **real** solution. A small note on the side: `Check()` could probably be `private`, and `Kill()` could call `Check()` before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can make them `public static`. This would be a rough code refactored to fix your compile errors.

```
public class notepad_check_class
{
    public static Process[] notepad_list;
    public static bool notepad_running;

    public static void notepad_check()
    {
        notepad_list = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

        notepad_running = notepad_list.Length > 0;
    }
}

public class kill_notepad_class
{
    public static void kill_notepad()
    {
        notepad_check_class.notepad_check();

        if (notepad_check_class.notepad_running)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to kill all notepad processes?", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                foreach (Process notepad_process in notepad_check_class.notepad_list)
                {
                    notepad_process.Kill();
                }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot find any running process of notepad.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class notepad_check_class
    {
        public int notepad_running;
        public static void notepad_check(notepad_check_class npc)
        {
            Process [] notepad_list = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            if (notepad_list.Length > 0)
            {
                npc.notepad_running = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public class kill_notepad_class
    {
        public notepad_check_class npc;
        public kill_notepad_class() {
           npc = new notepad_check_class();
        }
        public static void kill_notepad()
        {
            notepad_check_class.notepad_check(notepad_check_class npc);
            if (npc.notepad_running = 1)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to kill all notepad processes?", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    foreach (Process notepad_process in notepad_list)
                    {
                        notepad_process.Kill();
                    }
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find any running process of notepad.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

da da!

Comment: This code will complain for requiring an object instance in the line `if (npc.notepad_running = 1)` because it accessed from static context. Also same error on `notepad_running = 1;`